# alias in certificate

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

Why when I create a certificate in XCA software and import this to token and list certificate token in opensc, I don't see `alias`? But when I generate a certificate with openssl I have `alias`.

Comment: x509 has no standard attribute named "alias".

With Java's keytool, "alias" is used to uniquely name the record containing the certificate. I note that openssl also seems to have some concept of an alias (which I'd not come across before).

Are you talking about Subject Alternate Names?

Answer (score 1):

Due to [sourceforges step-by-step guide](http://xca.sourceforge.net/xca-14.html) you can set an `alias` for the canonical host name in the `Subject` tab during the creation of a CA-signed host certificate. The guide says:

> [...] For host certificates, the common name must be the FQDN to which
>   you wish users to connect. This need not be the canonical name of the
>   host, but can also be an alias. For example, if pluto.example.com is
>   your web server and it has a DNS CNAME entry of www.example.com, then
>   you probably want the Common Name value in the certificate to be
>   www.example.com. [...]

I this what you intend to do? If not, provide more information (if possible).

Comment: The advice at the link you provided is *very* dated. Modern browsers require the provided hostname to match one of Subject Alternate Names. Also the term "alias" is used in the generic sense in that article and not in relation to a named attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks but your answer not convincing, in certificate we have alias attribute but in viewer I do not see in, and what is usage of alias?